# Query for DC DNS entry domain.local. on DNS server 0.0.0.0 failed. Why 0.0.0.0?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows

Netdiag says "Query for DC DNS entry domain.local. on DNS server 0.0.0.0 failed." Why is the server 0.0.0.0? Like with my other question, all I find on the internet are netdiag logs, no explanation. 
The DNS server is actually set to 127.0.0.1 and Hosts says:

> 127.0.0.1       localhost

**Update:** domain.local is just a placeholder for the actual domain name.

Comment: `local.` is usually used for Zeroconf, but I don't know if 2008 is smart enough to realize this and do a mDNS lookup instead.

Comment: Sorry. domain.local is just a placeholder for the actual domain name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the DNS server to query is not setup correctly on the machine. What is the output of `ipconfig` ?

Comment: DNS servers are set to  ::1 and                                      127.0.0.1

Comment: If you run "nslookup" on this machine, do names resolve correctly?

Comment: Yes they do resolve correctly.